# How to use single subform in multiple views in Zend

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework

I am new bie with Zend framework. One of my application carries dynamic Drop down list of `country,state, district, city` in multiple views. 
So I would like to keep this as a common component and render anywhere with our needs. Can anybody can suggest me a simple and better solution to achieve this with Zend framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need these lists in a Form a good choice could be to write a sub-form and call it where you need. If you need these lists in the views, a good choice could be a view-helper.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own class which extends Zend_Form_Element_Library and i.e. place it in the library folder.

I usually create my own folder in /library (i.e. called MyApp) and put there all my classes (names start with 'MyApp_') which extend Zend classes. I also add a namespace to the config so as to load that classes automatically.